# Snooks slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen the slideshow, I got all the code from there but the images never disappear, they are added in front of the old ones and it overcharges my website. Anyone knows how to solve it? Here's the code:

```
<style>
  .fadein { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
  .fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
</style>

<div class="fadein">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>

$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
```

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vaysskc/), it works, but in my website, it doesn't. Any help?

***MORE INFORMATION***

- This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCncA.png) is from the console, so you can see the amount of images that are created..
- No errors in console.

***EDIT***

I went to get another slideshow from the same site, but so I could get multiple, and got what I wanted except one thing, the fadeIn is bugged, it starts to fade but then it cancels and changes to the next image.

```
<style>
.multipleslides { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; float:left; }
.multipleslides > * { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; display:block; }
</style>
<div class="multipleslides">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
<script>
      $('.multipleslides').each(function(){
        // scope everything for each slideshow
        var $this = this;
        $('> :gt(0)', $this).hide();
        setInterval(function(){$('> :first-child',$this).fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo($this);}, 4000);
      })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean in your computer it doesn't?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Like I said in the beggining, it doens't fadeIn or fadeOut, it just puts images in front of another images and it overloads my website

Comment: The fiddle is loading jQuery. Are you loading that in your page on your site?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Jquery 3.2.1 to be precise

Comment: Are you running the slideshow code within `document.ready()`?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I was not, but I changed it and it's still the same

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody No errors in console

Comment: is your jquery code being loaded?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I think it is. When I go to performance and check jquery.3.2.1.js it says 0 ms

Comment: How is the jQuery code for transitioning the images being loaded on your page? Is it within a `<script>jQuery Code</script>` tag, or loaded as an external file with `<script scr="path/to/your/jsfile.js"></script>`?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody It was trhough the same page, but check my edit.

Comment: Ok, so the code is pretty different from the original jsFiddle. And when I view it in jsFiddle there are some syntax errors, as well as other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some updates to your code that should fix the slideshow. There were some syntax errors and I also made the selectors a bit easier to read, imo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.multipleslides').each(function() {
    // scope everything for each slideshow
    $(this).children('img').not(":eq(0)").hide();
   
    setInterval(function() {
  $(this).children('img').first().fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo($(this));
    }.bind($(this)), 4000);
  });
});
```

```css
.multipleslides {
  position: relative;
  height: 332px;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

.multipleslides>* {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="multipleslides">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg">
  <img src="https://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg">
</div>
```